# How to store array of groups in HDF5, one by one?

Tags: c++, caffe, hdf5

I'm having trouble finding the right documentation/examples for a task I've got. I want to store groups(?) which each contain:

- one 8-bit RGB image
- one 16-bit Grayscale image
- one array of unsigned short values.

And I want to do this one by one. I.e. I'll perform some preprocessing to obtain the components of the group and then I want to store these before I move on to the next one. One thing to keep in mind is that I don't know how many such groups will end up being written. My idea would have been to create a new group directly under root every time, naming it by the current count, but I have a feeling there's a more elegant way to solve this. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I realize I only added the C++ tag and didn't mention it in the text. I'm stuck with C++ on this and can't use python.

EDIT2: This will later be used by the hdf5 layer in caffe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to bother much, since the C++ API for HDF5 doesn't support images.

Answer (score 0):

I think your initial idea is perfectly okay. Just name them `foo1`, ..., `foo42`, but also add an attribute containing the total number of groups to root (and update that each time you add a group).